# body onload="" cannot find function

Tags: javascript, webgl

i am trying stuff with philogl library, and when i wrote,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>PGL2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PhiloGL.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function webGLStart(){
        alert('I m alive');
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="webGLStart();">
<canvas id="c" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

everything works fine, but if i write some philogl in it like,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>PGL2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PhiloGL.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function webGLStart(){
        var triangle = new PhiloGL.O3D.Model({
            vertices: [[0,1,0],[-1,-1,0],[1,-1,0]],
            colors: [[1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1]]
            });
        var square = new PhiloGL.O3D.Model({
            vertices: [[1,1,0],[-1,1,0],[1,-1,0],[-1,-1,0]],
            colors: [[0.5,0.5,1,1],[0.5,0.5,1,1]],[0.5,0.5,1,1]
            });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="webGLStart();">
<canvas id="c" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

chrome and firefox gives me an error that says webGLStart() is not defined.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Beside [Pointy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117536/body-onload-cannot-find-function/5117571#5117571) I recommend [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (an add-on for Firefox), it shows many things about JavaScript, and helps you finding what you messed up.

Comment: sorry but the main problem is i have to use chrome for now because firefox is right now lacks support of webGL, and even v4b11 does gives me errors on every webgl demo's website, if there were any good standalone app for this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line:

```
        colors: [[0.5,0.5,1,1],[0.5,0.5,1,1]],[0.5,0.5,1,1]
```

is syntactically incorrect: a closing "]" is in the wrong place. Thus the function definition "failed", so to speak, and the function doesn't really exist.

I literally just woke up so I'm not sure what's wrong with me that I could spot that.

Comment: yes this workds, but what suprised me is, only one line of the code is wrong and i am getting an error about "function is not defined", what is the best way of getting real error messages?

Comment: Try with Firebug (see my comment to your question), it says at which line of your code the error happened.

Comment: @gkaykck Firefox is really bad about reporting parse problems like that, but the errors usually show up in the Firebug console. An error encountered when *parsing* a function definition will result in the function being undefined; the runtime just doesn't have anything to work with in a case like that. Generally the entire `<script>` block is aborted!

Comment: sorry but the main problem is i have to use chrome for now because firefox is right now lacks support of webGL, and even v4b11 does gives me errors on every webgl demo's website, if there were any good standalone app for this...

Comment: Ah well Chrome has its own debugger, and it reports such errors as faithfully as Firefox does in my experience. Yet if you don't have the debug console open, you don't see them. That's one thing I appreciate about IE, even though it can be annoying: those "Error on page" warnings are useful. (Of course I realize you definitely can't use IE here :-)

Comment: +1 and standing ovation for this answer. I read it and immediately spotted my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error in the way you are using this "philogl", preventing the function from being interpreted fully. In particular, you have a syntax error with your square brackets. The function then remains undefined.

In future you can turn on the error console in Firebug (or the equivalent for your preferred browser) to see what you're doing wrong.

Also, prefer `document.onload = function() { ... }` in a script, instead of embedding scripting in HTML tags.